# How to Save the drawing (contents) from a panel into any format on a physical storage with C#? (WinForms)

Tags: c#, image, drawing

Can someone tell me what i don't make as it should, why i cannot save the drawing to a physical storage?

```
    private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Pen p = new Pen(Color.Red, 3);
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(700, 900);
        Graphics gr = this.CreateGraphics();

        gr.DrawLine(p, new Point(30, 30), new Point(80, 120));
        gr.DrawEllipse(p, 30, 30, 80, 120);

       //when i do this way it saves only a black rectangle, without other drawn content
       bmp.Save(@"C:\testBMP.jpeg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);


       // If i use the following 2 commented lines it saves only a empty rectangle.

       //Rectangle rec = new Rectangle(0, 0, 700, 900);
       // panel1.DrawToBitmap(bmp, rec);


    }
```

Thank you for advice!

Comment: Are you sure that you want to save the bitmap inside your panel's `Paint` event? This means you will create a new file each time your form is redrawn. You should do this somewhere else, e.g. when a button is clicked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two problems here.

1. **Drawing your panel's contents.** This should be done inside its `Paint` event handler, like this:

   ```
   private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
   {
       using (Pen p = new Pen(Color.Red, 3))
       {
           // get the panel's Graphics instance
           Graphics gr = e.Graphics;

           // draw to panel
           gr.DrawLine(p, new Point(30, 30), new Point(80, 120));
           gr.DrawEllipse(p, 30, 30, 80, 120);
       }
   }
   ```
2. **Saving your panel's contents as an image.** This part should be done **somewhere else** (for example, when you click on a "Save" button):

   ```
   private void saveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
        int width = panel1.Size.Width;
        int height = panel1.Size.Height;

        using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(width, height))
        {
            panel1.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height));
            bmp.Save(@"C:\testBMP.jpeg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you! This solved my problem and, the leading fact is that clarified that the saving action should be done on another method that in the Paint event (wasntme)

Comment: @meorfi: I am glad it helped, and one more thing to mention: whenever you create a new object which implements `IDisposable` (like `Pen` or `Bitmap`, for example), you should dispose it manually immediately after use (this is what `using` statements do). Most classes involved with drawing are disposable, so keep this in mind whenever you are doing something involving `Graphics`. `Graphics` is also disposable, but we are not creating it (it is stored inside the `e.Graphics` property), so is should not be disposed in this case.

Comment: Since you are using a simple color pen, you can just use Pens.Red instead of creating a new one.  Don't dispose it though!

Answer (score 3):

The instance gr has nothing to do with your bitmap (bmp).  So you're creating graphics that are associated with the form or control, and have a separate bitmap.  When you save the bitmap, you haven't drawn anything in it.

Comment: is it any way to associate graphics drawn on control with the bitmap object and after that to save it ?

Comment: Groo helped me :) if you are interest see his response.

Comment: @meorfi - Groo has a good response.  I had to go into a meeting!

Answer (score 1):

You need to get a Graphics object from the Image, not from your form. I have not tested this, but it should work.

```
private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    using (Pen p = new Pen(Color.Red, 3))
    using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(700, 900))
    using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
    {
       gr.DrawLine(p, new Point(30, 30), new Point(80, 120));
       gr.DrawEllipse(p, 30, 30, 80, 120);

       bmp.Save(@"C:\testBMP.jpeg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you. All drawn content appeared on the physical image. Is it any way to set the background of image? I see that teh black background is present in the physical file ...